# This source was included by my_file.dart via a #source directive, so cannot itself contain directives

Tags: dart

I don't think I understand this error message. Does it mean that my_file.dart was already sourced by another file e.g. my_main.dart contains:

```
#source('my_file.dart');
```

and so my_file.dart can't source other files? e.g in my_file.dart.

```
#source('my_other_file.dart'); // this can't be here?

class MyClass {
  Collection<MyOtherClass> myVariables;
}
```

The thing is, I have to source my_other_file.dart in my_file.dart because it gives errors about "no such type" for classes in my_other_file.dart if I don't. But when I do, I get that title error, "This source was included by my_file.dart via a #source directive, so cannot itself contain directives".

Have I completely misinterpreted this message? How do I make these errors stop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your understanding is right, a `#source`-d file cannot `#source` other files.

But let's get deeper: Dart supports libraries. For example, if you use Dart on the server, you will most likely use the `dart:io` library (by writing `#import('dart:io')` in your code). If you use Dart in the browser, you will most likely use the `dart:html` library. The `dart:core` library is implicitly imported in every program.

You can of course write your own libraries. In almost all cases, a library will span over more that one file. In this case, *one* of these files will be somewhat *main*: it will declare the library (using `#library`), specify all dependencies (using `#import`) and all other source files (using `#source`). All other files (those `#source`-d ones) will only contain Dart code and none of them can contain these `#library`, `#import` and `#source` directives. It can look like this:

my_lib.dart:

```
#library('My Library');

#source('my_lib_impl.dart');

interface MyInterface default _MyClass {
  foo();
}
```

my_lib_impl.dart:

```
class _MyClass implements MyInterface {
  foo() {
    print("foo!");
  }
}
```

Then, if you want to use this library in your program, you *have to* `#import` the `my_lib.dart` file. You *don't* `#source` it.

my_program.dart:

```
#import('my_lib.dart');

main() {
  new MyInterface().foo();
}
```

Note that here, even if `my_program.dart` doesn't contain a `#library` directive, it works like one -- it can `#import` and `#source` files. You can do that in the "entrypoint" script.

I tried to explain how to use libraries in Dart, which isn't a direct answer to your question, but it should help. If not, please let me know and I'll try to dig deeper.

Answer (score 2):

Ladicek has the full explanation. Regarding your specific problem:

> I have to source my_other_file.dart in my_file.dart because it gives errors about "no such type" for classes in my_other_file.dart if I don't. But when I do, I get that title error, "This source was included by my_file.dart via a #source directive, so cannot itself contain directives".

The fix is: Instead of putting `#source('my_other_file.dart')` in `my_file.dart`, put it in `my_main.dart`.

We on the Dart team are aware this is one of the really confusing corners of the language, and we're working to try to come up with something better, but it takes time.